# Insert or update on constraint in Ecto format

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Below is the direct sql query,

```
insert into reports as rp (time_track, affiliate_manager_id)
values (#{time_track},#{revenue})
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT report_base_ids
  DO UPDATE SET revenue = 1
```

How it can be written in Ecto Elixir.

I Tried with

```
Report.upsert_by(:)
```

but it is not giving option to mention constraint

Comment: What is `Report.upsert_by`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `conflict_target:` as `{:constraint, constraint_name_as_atom}` to `Repo.insert` or `Repo.insert_all` along with `on_conflict:` with the update instructions. Here's an example:

```
Repo.insert(
  Schema, # module
  %{foo: "bar"}, # data
  on_conflict: [set: [revenue: 1]],
  conflict_target: {:constraint, :report_base_ids}
)
```

You can read more about it in the documentation of [`Repo.insert`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert/2), specifically the section on `:on_conflict` and `:conflict_target`.